# xcode: Avoiding link conflicts with a static library

Tags: xcode, opencv, linker, static-libraries

We're developing an SDK for our technology for iOS, the sdk is delivered in a static framework. Our code uses openCV and we link OpenCV into the delivered framework binary.
This normally works well but we're having an issue with a client which is indirectly using a different version of openCV in another framework.
This is causing a conflict and the clients app crashes.

Beside switching to the same version of openCV, removing our openCV dependency or switching to a dynamic library (which allows to hide open CV inside), is there an another option to fix this?

I tried to compile our lib using "Perform Single-Object Prelink and add the openCV libs in "Prelink libraries" but this produced link error when I tried to integrate it and it looks as if it ignored "Prelink libraries", maybe I'm doing something wrong here.

Any thoughts or ideas on the matter would be much appreciated.